# How to add Mailchip Popup Form to my website

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup, mailchimp

can some one help me add my Mailchimp Popup Form to my website.  I have coded the website myself I am NOT using WordPress.  I have the JavaScript code from Mailchimp and googled loads of answers but nothing is working.  So far I have this is the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
```

and this before the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMailingPopUp() {
window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us18.list-manage.com","uuid":"acdbc8c4ea3fc5657817d4ea9","lid":"f5d8b25789","uniqueMethods":true}) })
```

};
    document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {showMailingPopUp()};

I want the pop up to open when you click on a button so added this to my button

```
    <button id="open-popup">Take the Quiz</button>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the button.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks

Comment: have you tried to use first some of the mailchimp predefined templates, just to see that everything works from html?

Comment: Yes I tried an embedded form and that worked it's just not the one I want :)